# Changing the Python interpreter for Inkscape

Tags: python, inkscape

I keep getting errors when using Inkscape that seem to imply that a python 2 vs 3 expectation isn't being met, though I have both of them installed. For instance, when I try to make a new document generated from a template, I get,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "empty_generic.py", line 82, in <module>
    c.affect()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 285, in affect
    self.output()
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 272, in output
    self.document.write(sys.stdout)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2033, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.write (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:63667)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 524, in lxml.etree._tofilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:134877)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 324, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:10737)
  File "src/lxml/serializer.pxi", line 441, in lxml.etree._FilelikeWriter.write (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:133581)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

where the last line seems to be just what I said-- usually this error is caused by running python 2 code with a python 3 interpreter, and can be fixed by simply passing the string object str as `str.decode()` or something. Obviously, though, editing the inkscape source code is not an ideal solution.

Also, when trying to generate a Voronoi diagram, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voronoi2svg.py", line 36, in <module>
    import simplepath
  File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/simplepath.py", line 51
    raise Exception, 'Invalid path data!'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

which again seems like an obvious 2 vs. 3 error.

Is there a way to change the python interpreter being used by Inkscape?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I Actually found the answer to my issue from the Inkscape site itself [here](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Extension_requirements):

> If your operating system (e.g. your Linux distro) uses a different default version of Python (or Perl, Ruby, etc.) than what is required by Inkscape extensions, please see Extension Interpreters for how to set the interpreter that Inkscape will use. The most common example of this is that the default Python version of the operating system is 3, but Inkscape requires Python2, resulting in all extensions giving an error.

which [leads to this page](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Extension_Interpreters#Selecting_a_specific_interpreter_version_.28via_preferences_file.29), which says:

> Selecting a specific interpreter version (via preferences file) In the
>   preferences.xml file, a user can set a specific executable of the
>   interpreter that Inkscape should use to execute extensions of a
>   specific type.
>
> This is especially useful, if the system's default version of the
>   interpreter is incompatible with the one used by Inkscape's extension
>   subsystem (e.g. Inkscape extensions that rely on inkex.py will only
>   work with Python 2 (as of Inkscape 0.92.1), while on some recent Linux
>   distributions, the default Python version used is Python 3, which
>   results in errors during execution of extensions).
>
> To change the executable that will be used to run script extensions to
>   a different value than the default value in the above table, you need
>   to do the following:
>
> quit all running Inkscape processes Open your perferences.xml file
>   with a text editor (find the exact location of the file by going to
>   Edit -> Preferences -> System: User Preferences) search the group
>   which holds settings for the extension system itself and options of
>   various extensions:
>
> ```
> <group
>  id="extensions"
>  …
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.teeth="24"
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.pitch="20"
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.angle="20" />
> ```
>
> Insert a key for the interpreter, for example 'python-interpreter' for
>   setting the program that should be used to run python extensions, and
>   set the string to the absolute path to the python binary which is
>   compatible with Inkscape's current extension scripts (in the example
>   below, the path is "/usr/bin/python2.7". It will look different on
>   Windows systems.):
>
> ```
> <group
>  id="extensions"
>  python-interpreter="/usr/bin/python2.7"
>  …
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.teeth="24"
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.pitch="20"
>  org.ekips.filter.gears.angle="20" />
> ```
>
> Save the preferences file, and launch Inkscape to test the extensions.

Comment: Remember to edit the preference file when Inkscape is close, in other case it will be overwritten and you will lose your changes

Comment: I changed to `python-interpreter="/usr/bin/python3.7`. Syntax errors disappeared, but when I clicked on 'Apply', nothing happened. No error popped nor did the gcode file got generated.

Comment: I solved it. It was `/home/username/anaconda3/bin/python` for me. I went to `view>messages` to see the logs and clicked on `capture log messages`. Then I found the reason for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer help me.  But I went another way.  Using setting a local python in the `.config/inkscape/extension` folder with `pyenv local 2.7.18`.  Installing with it any python dependencies required and it worked.

Changing the setting a python-interpreter did not work for me.